# How to line (cut) a dendrogram at the best K

Tags: r, plot, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

How do I draw a line in a dendrogram that **corresponds the best K** for a given criteria?

Like this:

[image]

Lets suppose that this is my dendrogram, and the best K is 4.

```
data("mtcars")
myDend <-  as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mtcars))) 
plot(myDend)
```

I know that `abline` function is able to draw lines in graphs similarly to the one showed above. However, I don't know how could I calculate the height, so the function is used as `abline(h = myHeight)`

Comment: what method are you using to determine "best"?

Comment: For a more serious task I'm using SIlhouette. The best K in the question was completely arbitrary because my doubt is in how to draw a line given a `k` or how to determine the height, given a k

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information that you need to get the heights came with `hclust`. It has a variable containing the heights. To get the 4 clusters,  you want to draw your line between the 3rd biggest and 4th biggest height.

```
HC = hclust(dist(mtcars))
myDend <-  as.dendrogram(HC) 

par(mar=c(7.5,4,2,2))
plot(myDend)

k = 4
n = nrow(mtcars)
MidPoint = (HC$height[n-k] + HC$height[n-k+1]) / 2
abline(h = MidPoint, lty=2)
```

[image: Dendrogram]